# ActionBar logo paddings after orientation change

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I am using actionbar sherlock and i am using this piece of code to remove the top and bottom paddings of actionbar logo so that it can look bigger.

```
    ImageView icon = (ImageView) findViewById(android.R.id.home);
    FrameLayout.LayoutParams iconLp = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) icon.getLayoutParams();
    iconLp.height=LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
    iconLp.topMargin = iconLp.bottomMargin = 0;
    icon.setLayoutParams( iconLp );
```

But when the orientation of the screen changes the paddings go back to default and logo looks smaller again. I tried calling this code in `onConfigurationChange` but it doesnt have any change.

How can i solve this problem?

Thanks

Comment: can you post the entire code. and when does the above code executed?

Comment: This code piece is onResume or onCreate,i tried both.Everything works perfectly till the orientation change. on my manifest the config change attribute is like this `android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"`. And i need it to be this way.